# Python. Calling openssl.exe in Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python script that needs to call openssl.exe in Windows. Here's the script:

```
import os
import subprocess
#print("Starting startfile method")
#os.startfile('openssl.exe req -out server.csr -newkey:4096 -nodes -keyout server.priv.key -config server.cnf')
#print("Starting Popen method")
#subprocess.Popen('openssl.exe req -out server.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server.priv.key -config server.cnf')
#print("Starting run method")
#subprocess.run(['openssl.exe', 'req -out server.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server.priv.key -config server.cnf'])
#print("Starting call method")
#subprocess.call('openssl.exe req -out server.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server.priv.key -config server.cnf')
#print("Done")
```

If I uncomment the "os.startfile" line, I get a file not found error. That makes sense. os.startfile can't handle arguments (is that correct?)

If I uncomment the subprocess.Popen line, openssl starts, performs as it should, then hangs. openssl.exe process never exits, and so the script doesn't finish. That really perplexes me.

If I uncomment the subprocess.run line, then openssl.exe gives me an error that "req -out... is not a valid command" Is that because openssl.exe doesn't like arguments given through stdin?

If I uncomment the subprocess.call line, openssl.exe behaves exactly as it should (that is, as if it were run from Windows command line), and it exits and allows the Python script to continue.

Can you help me understand the differences between the these different methods of calling external processes?

Comment: When using `subprocess` calls, you need `shell=True` when you pass a single string.

Comment: ...remember, `openssl.exe req` isn't a file that exists. `openssl.exe` is a file; you can only call it on its own, without a bunch of extra cruft in the same string, unless you have other tools doing word-splitting / deciding when spaces are syntax as opposed to part of the filename.

Comment: And `req` is **one** argument; `-out` is **a second** argument; etc. Quote each argument separately. You couldn't put quotes around `"req -out"` in the shell command line, so you can't have them quoted into the same Python string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting each of these in turn:

```
import os
import subprocess

print("Starting startfile method")
os.startfile('openssl.exe', arguments='req -out server.csr -newkey:4096 -nodes -keyout server.priv.key -config server.cnf')

print("Starting Popen method with shell=True (bad)")
subprocess.Popen('openssl.exe req -out server.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server.priv.key -config server.cnf', shell=True)

print("Starting Popen method with shell=False (good)")
subprocess.Popen(['openssl.exe', 'req', '-out', 'server.csr', '-newkey', 'rsa:4096', '-nodes', '-keyout', 'server.priv.key', '-config', 'server.cnf'])

print("Starting run method")
subprocess.run(['openssl.exe', 'req', '-out', 'server.csr', '-newkey', 'rsa:4096', '-nodes', '-keyout', 'server.priv.key', '-config', 'server.cnf'])

print("Starting call method")
subprocess.call(['openssl.exe', 'req', '-out', 'server.csr', '-newkey', 'rsa:4096', '-nodes', '-keyout', 'server.priv.key', '-config', 'server.cnf')

print("Done")
```

Rules that apply across all of these:

- When there's no shell word-splitting on spaces, you can't put multiple arguments together into a single space-separated string; they need to each be separate.
- For all `subprocess`-family items, word-splitting is only offered when `shell=True`. However, adding a shell creates room for bugs and security exposure; it should only be done when you have no other choice.
- Windows is unlike every other major operating system in that it makes programs responsible for parsing their own command lines (and thus lets each program parse its own command line in a different, incompatible way from how any other program works, should it choose to override the standard C library default behavior). Thus, only the Windows-specific `os.startfile` method allows arguments to be passed in a single string without having a shell or other software component responsible for separating them.

Answer (score 1):

`startfile` is specific to Windows and does take arguments. The error here is not separating the arguments with a comma. (I'm assuming the arguments themselves are correct)

`startfile` will start a new file completely separately from the program it is called from. So there is no data that could be returned to the calling program.
`subprocess` runs the file "inside" the calling program so that data such as a return code can be accessed by the calling program.

Comment: What do you mean about "not separating the arguments with a comma"? As the docs say, `os.startfile` should take _a single string_ in the `arguments` position.

Comment: yeah it is ok now since it has been changed - before it looked like everything was intended as argument (not arguing or anything!! :))